# EF Code-First constraints for auto generated Many-Many relationship

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, ef-code-first

For the purpose of this question I have 3 entities: Account, Person and Event.

An Account contains things pertaining to "login" information.

Person contains information such as name, DOB etc.

Events are different happenings that people can attend.

There is a 1-1 relationship between Account and Person. The Person primary key references the Account primary key, and as such must be connected with an account.

There is a many-1 relationship between Account and Event. An account can create many events, but each event may only have 1 creator.

There is a many-many relationship between Person and Event. Many people may attend many events.

```
public class Account
{
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Event> CreatedEvents { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Event> ParticipatingIn { get; set; }
}

public class Event
{
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public int CreatorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Account Creator { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Participants { get; set; }
}
```

Account / Person relationship is configured as such:

```
public AccountEntityConfiguration()
{
    this.HasRequired(a => a.Person)
        .WithRequiredPrincipal(p => p.Account)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

    this.HasMany(a => a.CreatedEvents)
        .WithRequired()
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.CreatorId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}

public PersonEntityConfiguration()
{
    this.HasMany(p => p.ParticipatingIn)
        .WithMany();    
}
```

My problem is this:

When an Account is deleted, the associated Person is deleted. As such, the relevant row in the PersonsEvents table must be deleted.

When an event is deleted, the row referencing the event in the PersonEvents link-table must be deleted.

If an Account is the creator of an event, there is nothing stopping the Person associated with the Account to also participate in the event. If the account is then deleted, the deletion cascades to Events created by the Account, which cascades to the PersonsEvents table. At the same time, the associated Person is deleted, which cascades to the PersonsEvents table, and now there's a conflict.

In my code it is easy to check that my PersonId is not the same as my CreatorId when I try to assign a person to the event, but how do I ensure the same check in my database? Because of the conflict, I cannot enable cascade deletion on both the Person and Event foreign key in the PersonsEvents table, which I need.

Comment: why not deactivating the account instead of deleting it

Comment: Because I want to be able to delete it from the database.

Comment: I mean make a boolean representing the state of this account and treat the record as history

Comment: Your problem isn't with EF it is with buisness